# Ruby JSON parses nested hash with an array

Tags: ruby, json, hash

The following code will return `Hash` for `doc.class`, and list of keys for `doc`.

```
url = "http://www.theskinfood.co.kr/goods/getGoodsList.ajax?catTpCd=176100&catCd=4000000077&rec=25&numb=1&allRow=0&sortTy=&searchVal=+"
doc = Crack::JSON.parse(open(url).read)
puts doc.class
puts doc.keys
puts doc['resultList'].class
```

There are nested hashes that I would like to get to, but the class of them returns as an array. I would like to parse all `"goodsCd"` key values, but at this time, the only alternative is turning that array into a long string and regexing it through.

Hope someone can point out a more elegant way, preferably searching through nested hash (first parsing it correctly) and looking for `key=value` pair.

Comment: `puts doc['resultList'][0].class` returns hash... so I guess I can loop the array and search for nested keys within. Can there be another way?

Comment: If you post an example of the data structure, you increase your chances of a good answer. :-)